# setState() in a child widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an array with widgets and a index. With the Index I know which widget is selected. The array of the widgets are in the boddy. How can I use setState() in one of the widgets in the Array?
On the position where I want to use setState is a comment with setState()????

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  List<Widgets> _widgetOptions = <Widget> [
.
.
.
      Container(
                    margin:
                        new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(
                            videoslist[index].isFavorite
                                ? Icons.star
                                : Icons.star_border,
                            color: Colors.yellowAccent[200],
                            size: 40),
                            onPressed: () {
                              //setState????  
                            },

                      ),
                    ),
                  )
]




@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("")
        leading: new Image.asset(
          'assets/icon2.png',
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: 
        _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex), //Array with widgets
      ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set state can be called in you example, but it will need to update a variable. I have modified your example to change the color;

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

@override
void initState() {
    _color = Colors.yellowAccent[200];
    super.initState();
}

Color _color;

  List<Widgets> _widgetOptions = <Widget> [
.
.
.
      Container(
                    margin:
                        new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(
                            videoslist[index].isFavorite
                                ? Icons.star
                                : Icons.star_border,
                            color: _color,
                            size: 40),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState((){
                                 _color = Colors.Red;
                              });
                            },

                      ),
                    ),
                  )
]
```

Comment: Okey I will try it today